# SUMIF Excel, avoiding additional column

Tags: excel

I have a quite simple question but somehow I cannot find the right - nice solution - hoping you guys can help me.
Suppose you have an excel table (I need to solve this in excel, I can do it in python - what an irony)

```
Search field     Range                 Entry      Sum
BB.13180.01     BB.13180.01            1.00       7
                BB.13180.01.01         2.00
                BB.13180.01.02         3.00 
                BB.13180.01            1.00
```

What I want to achieve is the following:
Sum the entries of column "Entry" only if the item in Search field is equal to the 11 first elements of column Range

I only can achieve this solution by adding an additional column and using the LEFT function and extracting the 11 elements from column "Range" and then apply the SUMIF function

Any ideas how I can solve this little issue without having an additional column?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUMIFS()` with wildcard option. Try-

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,A2&"*")
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet that works,
can you kindly explain for a non-excel expert what the "*" is doing?

Comment: @SMS It is wildcard meaning start with. So, `A2&"*"` means `BB.13180.01*` which will match `BB.13180.01` to all values of column B while `*` will ignore all characters after `BB.13180.01`.

Comment: `Asterisk` `*` - zero or more characters it means that. And concatenating with `A2` using `Ampersand` `&` means to match with those starts with `A2` and end with its any number of characters. So in your example it matches with all of those present in Column `B` and `*` doesnt means start with.

Comment: One quick search in google abt `wildcard` lands to this page **[Wildcard-Operator-In-Excel](https://exceljet.net/glossary/wildcard#:~:text=Excel%20has%203%20wildcards%20you%20can%20use%20in,question%20mark%20%28~%3F%29%2C%20or%20a%20literal%20tilde%20%28~~%29.)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat() to assemble the criteria.
`=SUMIF(D2:D5;CONCAT(C2;"*");E2:E5)`
where there is

- `D2:25`: the range where to search
- `C2`: the search value
- `E2:E5`: the range for the SUM()

Answer (score 0):

SUMIF(B2:B6,"BB.13180.01*",C2:C6)

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).